# StructureMap Initialize web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, structuremap

I have a very strange problem.  In my MVC 4 application I have this code to initialize StructureMap :

```
public static class IoC {
public static IContainer Initialize() {
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                {
                    x.Scan(scan =>
                            {
                                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                            });
                    x.For<IRestHttpClient>().Use<AtlamHttpClient>().Ctor<string>().Is(Settings.AtlamServicesURL);
                });
    ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return ObjectFactory.Container;
}
```

}

that works as expected.  However, I also have a .NET 4.5 Web forms application with the same basic initialization code:

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.AssemblyContainingType<IRestHttpClient>();
                    scan.AssemblyContainingType<MessagePackMediaTypeFormatter>();
                });
                x.For<IRestHttpClient>().Use<AtlamHttpClient>().Ctor<string>().Is(Settings.BaseServiceUrl);
                /*x.SetAllProperties(y =>
                    {
                        y.OfType<IRestHttpClient>();
                    });*/
            });
        ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

that throws an exception on AssertConfigurationIsValid() and is failing here in the AtlamHttpClient:

```
public static List<ContentNegotiator> extensionMappings = new List<ContentNegotiator>()
        {
            new ContentNegotiator("xml", "application/xml", new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()),
            new ContentNegotiator("json", "application/json", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            new ContentNegotiator("pack", "application/x-msgpack", new MessagePackMediaTypeFormatter())
        };
```

which in turn calls:

```
public MessagePackMediaTypeFormatter()
        {
            MediaTypeHeaderValue val = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(mime);
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(val);
        }
```

and fails with an ArrayTypeMismatchException.  Can't figure out why the first project works fine and the second one is failing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add that both projects are using version 2.6.4 of StructureMap.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  Turns out the problem was that I had a binding redirect to version 2.0 of System.Net.Http.  Removed that and everything worked fine.